I'm trying to fine tune a model for a question-answer task, but I keep encountering errors. Why?
I'm trying to fine-tune a model for my thesis using the following dataset for question-and-answer tasks: https://huggingface.co/datasets/SzegedAI/MILQA/tree/main, in the following code:
`
import os
import json
import torch
from transformers import DefaultDataCollator, AutoModelForQuestionAnswering, AutoTokenizer, Trainer, TrainingArguments, \
    TrainerCallback
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from torch.utils.data import Dataset


class PlotCallback(TrainerCallback):
    def __init__(self):
        self.train_losses = []
        self.eval_losses = []
        self.eval_steps = []

    def on_log(self, args, state, control, logs=None, **kwargs):
        if state.is_world_process_zero:
            if 'loss' in logs:
                self.train_losses.append(logs['loss'])
            if 'eval_loss' in logs:
                self.eval_losses.append(logs['eval_loss'])
                self.eval_steps.append(state.global_step)

    def on_train_end(self, args, state, control, **kwargs):
        # Tanulási veszteség diagram
        plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
        plt.plot(self.train_losses, label='Training Loss', color='blue')
        plt.title('Training Loss over Training Steps')
        plt.xlabel('Training Steps')
        plt.ylabel('Loss')
        plt.legend()
        plt.grid(True)
        plt.show()
class MyDataCollator(DefaultDataCollator):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def collate_batch(self, examples):
        contexts = [example['Context'] for example in examples]
        qa_lists = [example['Questions_Answers'] for example in examples]

        inputs = []
        labels = []

        for context, qa_list in zip(contexts, qa_lists):
            context_inputs = tokenizer(context, return_tensors="pt", padding=True, truncation=True)

            context_input_ids = context_inputs["input_ids"]
            context_attention_mask = context_inputs["attention_mask"]

            for qa in qa_list:
                question_inputs = tokenizer(qa['Question'], return_tensors="pt", padding=True, truncation=True)

                question_input_ids = question_inputs["input_ids"]
                question_attention_mask = question_inputs["attention_mask"]

                inputs.append((context_input_ids, context_attention_mask))
                labels.append((question_input_ids[0], question_attention_mask[0]))

        return {
            "input_ids": torch.nn.utils.rnn.pad_sequence([i[0] for i in inputs], batch_first=True),
            "attention_mask": torch.nn.utils.rnn.pad_sequence([i[1] for i in inputs], batch_first=True),
            "labels": torch.nn.utils.rnn.pad_sequence([l[0] for l in labels], batch_first=True),
            "labels_attention_mask": torch.nn.utils.rnn.pad_sequence([l[1] for l in labels], batch_first=True)
        }

class MyDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, batch):
        self.inputs = batch['input_ids']
        self.attention_masks = batch['attention_mask']
        self.labels = batch['labels']
        self.labels_attention_masks = batch['labels_attention_mask']

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.inputs)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        return {
            'input_ids': self.inputs[idx],
            'attention_mask': self.attention_masks[idx],
            'labels': self.labels[idx],
            'labels_attention_mask': self.labels_attention_masks[idx]
        }


with open("train.MILQA-2023-03-27.squad.s.json", "r", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    data = json.load(f)

inputs = []

for paragraph in data["data"][0]["paragraphs"]:
    context = paragraph["context"]
    qa_list = []
    for qa in paragraph["qas"]:
        question = qa["question"]
        short_answer = None
        long_answer = None
        short_start = None
        short_end = None
        long_start = None
        long_end = None
        if "answers" in qa:
            if "short" in qa["answers"]:
                short_answer = qa["answers"]["short"][0]["text"]
                short_start = qa["answers"]["short"][0]["start"]
                short_end = qa["answers"]["short"][0]["end"]
            if "long" in qa["answers"]:
                long_answer = qa["answers"]["long"][0]["text"]
                long_start = qa["answers"]["long"][0]["start"]
                long_end = qa["answers"]["long"][0]["end"]
        qa_list.append({'Question': question, 'Short Answer': short_answer, 'Long Answer': long_answer})
    inputs.append({'Context': context, 'Questions_Answers': qa_list})

for item in data["data"][1:]:
    for paragraph in item["paragraphs"]:
        context = paragraph["context"]
        qa_list = []
        for qa in paragraph["qas"]:
            question = qa["question"]
            short_answer = None
            long_answer = None
            short_start = None
            short_end = None
            long_start = None
            long_end = None
            if "answers" in qa:
                if "short" in qa["answers"]:
                    short_answer = qa["answers"]["short"][0]["text"]
                    short_start = qa["answers"]["short"][0]["start"]
                    short_end = qa["answers"]["short"][0]["end"]
                if "long" in qa["answers"]:
                    long_answer = qa["answers"]["long"][0]["text"]
                    long_start = qa["answers"]["long"][0]["start"]
                    long_end = qa["answers"]["long"][0]["end"]
            qa_list.append({'Question': question, 'Short Answer': short_answer, 'Long Answer': long_answer})
        inputs.append({'Context': context, 'Questions_Answers': qa_list})

model_name = 'TinyLlama/TinyLlama-1.1B-Chat-v1.0'
model = AutoModelForQuestionAnswering.from_pretrained(model_name)
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name)

data_collator = MyDataCollator()

batch = data_collator.collate_batch(inputs)

# Convert batch dictionary to a dataset object
train_dataset = MyDataset(batch)

output_dir = "./finetuned_model"
if not os.path.exists(output_dir):
    os.makedirs(output_dir)

training_args = TrainingArguments(
    output_dir=output_dir,
    overwrite_output_dir=True,
    num_train_epochs=2,
    learning_rate=2e-4,
    per_device_train_batch_size=2,
    warmup_ratio=0.1,
    lr_scheduler_type="linear",
    save_strategy="epoch"
)

trainer = Trainer(
    model=model,
    args=training_args,
    data_collator=data_collator,
    train_dataset=train_dataset,  # Pass the dataset object
    callbacks=[PlotCallback()],
)

trainer.train()

tokenizer.save_pretrained(output_dir)

`

However, I'm encountering the following errors:
C:\Users\Levente\Desktop\minigpt\.venv\Scripts\python.exe C:\Users\Levente\Desktop\minigpt\train.py 
2024-05-02 18:52:07.830258: I tensorflow/core/util/port.cc:113] oneDNN custom operations are on. You may see slightly different numerical results due to floating-point round-off errors from different computation orders. To turn them off, set the environment variable `TF_ENABLE_ONEDNN_OPTS=0`.
2024-05-02 18:52:08.401668: I tensorflow/core/util/port.cc:113] oneDNN custom operations are on. You may see slightly different numerical results due to floating-point round-off errors from different computation orders. To turn them off, set the environment variable `TF_ENABLE_ONEDNN_OPTS=0`.
Some weights of LlamaForQuestionAnswering were not initialized from the model checkpoint at TinyLlama/TinyLlama-1.1B-Chat-v1.0 and are newly initialized: ['embed_tokens.weight', 'layers.0.input_layernorm.weight', 'layers.0.mlp.down_proj.weight', 'layers.0.mlp.gate_proj.weight', 'layers.0.mlp.up_proj.weight', 'layers.0.post_attention_layernorm.weight', 'layers.0.self_attn.k_proj.weight', 'layers.0.self_attn.o_proj.weight', 'layers.0.self_attn.q_proj.weight', 'layers.0.self_attn.v_proj.weight', 'layers.1.input_layernorm.weight', 'layers.1.mlp.down_proj.weight', 'layers.1.mlp.gate_proj.weight', 'layers.1.mlp.up_proj.weight', 'layers.1.post_attention_layernorm.weight', 'layers.1.self_attn.k_proj.weight', 'layers.1.self_attn.o_proj.weight', 'layers.1.self_attn.q_proj.weight', 'layers.1.self_attn.v_proj.weight', 'layers.10.input_layernorm.weight', 'layers.10.mlp.down_proj.weight', 'layers.10.mlp.gate_proj.weight', 'layers.10.mlp.up_proj.weight', 'layers.10.post_attention_layernorm.weight', 'layers.10.self_attn.k_proj.weight', 'layers.10.self_attn.o_proj.weight', 'layers.10.self_attn.q_proj.weight', 'layers.10.self_attn.v_proj.weight', 'layers.11.input_layernorm.weight', 'layers.11.mlp.down_proj.weight', 'layers.11.mlp.gate_proj.weight', 'layers.11.mlp.up_proj.weight', 'layers.11.post_attention_layernorm.weight', 'layers.11.self_attn.k_proj.weight', 'layers.11.self_attn.o_proj.weight', 'layers.11.self_attn.q_proj.weight', 'layers.11.self_attn.v_proj.weight', 'layers.12.input_layernorm.weight', 'layers.12.mlp.down_proj.weight', 'layers.12.mlp.gate_proj.weight', 'layers.12.mlp.up_proj.weight', 'layers.12.post_attention_layernorm.weight', 'layers.12.self_attn.k_proj.weight', 'layers.12.self_attn.o_proj.weight', 'layers.12.self_attn.q_proj.weight', 'layers.12.self_attn.v_proj.weight', 'layers.13.input_layernorm.weight', 'layers.13.mlp.down_proj.weight', 'layers.13.mlp.gate_proj.weight', 'layers.13.mlp.up_proj.weight', 'layers.13.post_attention_layernorm.weight', 'layers.13.self_attn.k_proj.weight', 'layers.13.self_attn.o_proj.weight', 'layers.13.self_attn.q_proj.weight', 'layers.13.self_attn.v_proj.weight', 'layers.14.input_layernorm.weight', 'layers.14.mlp.down_proj.weight', 'layers.14.mlp.gate_proj.weight', 'layers.14.mlp.up_proj.weight', 'layers.14.post_attention_layernorm.weight', 'layers.14.self_attn.k_proj.weight', 'layers.14.self_attn.o_proj.weight', 'layers.14.self_attn.q_proj.weight', 'layers.14.self_attn.v_proj.weight', 'layers.15.input_layernorm.weight', 'layers.15.mlp.down_proj.weight', 'layers.15.mlp.gate_proj.weight', 'layers.15.mlp.up_proj.weight', 'layers.15.post_attention_layernorm.weight', 'layers.15.self_attn.k_proj.weight', 'layers.15.self_attn.o_proj.weight', 'layers.15.self_attn.q_proj.weight', 'layers.15.self_attn.v_proj.weight', 'layers.16.input_layernorm.weight', 'layers.16.mlp.down_proj.weight', 'layers.16.mlp.gate_proj.weight', 'layers.16.mlp.up_proj.weight', 'layers.16.post_attention_layernorm.weight', 'layers.16.self_attn.k_proj.weight', 'layers.16.self_attn.o_proj.weight', 'layers.16.self_attn.q_proj.weight', 'layers.16.self_attn.v_proj.weight', 'layers.17.input_layernorm.weight', 'layers.17.mlp.down_proj.weight', 'layers.17.mlp.gate_proj.weight', 'layers.17.mlp.up_proj.weight', 'layers.17.post_attention_layernorm.weight', 'layers.17.self_attn.k_proj.weight', 'layers.17.self_attn.o_proj.weight', 'layers.17.self_attn.q_proj.weight', 'layers.17.self_attn.v_proj.weight', 'layers.18.input_layernorm.weight', 'layers.18.mlp.down_proj.weight', 'layers.18.mlp.gate_proj.weight', 'layers.18.mlp.up_proj.weight', 'layers.18.post_attention_layernorm.weight', 'layers.18.self_attn.k_proj.weight', 'layers.18.self_attn.o_proj.weight', 'layers.18.self_attn.q_proj.weight', 'layers.18.self_attn.v_proj.weight', 'layers.19.input_layernorm.weight', 'layers.19.mlp.down_proj.weight', 'layers.19.mlp.gate_proj.weight', 'layers.19.mlp.up_proj.weight', 'layers.19.post_attention_layernorm.weight', 'layers.19.self_attn.k_proj.weight', 'layers.19.self_attn.o_proj.weight', 'layers.19.self_attn.q_proj.weight', 'layers.19.self_attn.v_proj.weight', 'layers.2.input_layernorm.weight', 'layers.2.mlp.down_proj.weight', 'layers.2.mlp.gate_proj.weight', 'layers.2.mlp.up_proj.weight', 'layers.2.post_attention_layernorm.weight', 'layers.2.self_attn.k_proj.weight', 'layers.2.self_attn.o_proj.weight', 'layers.2.self_attn.q_proj.weight', 'layers.2.self_attn.v_proj.weight', 'layers.20.input_layernorm.weight', 'layers.20.mlp.down_proj.weight', 'layers.20.mlp.gate_proj.weight', 'layers.20.mlp.up_proj.weight', 'layers.20.post_attention_layernorm.weight', 'layers.20.self_attn.k_proj.weight', 'layers.20.self_attn.o_proj.weight', 'layers.20.self_attn.q_proj.weight', 'layers.20.self_attn.v_proj.weight', 'layers.21.input_layernorm.weight', 'layers.21.mlp.down_proj.weight', 'layers.21.mlp.gate_proj.weight', 'layers.21.mlp.up_proj.weight', 'layers.21.post_attention_layernorm.weight', 'layers.21.self_attn.k_proj.weight', 'layers.21.self_attn.o_proj.weight', 'layers.21.self_attn.q_proj.weight', 'layers.21.self_attn.v_proj.weight', 'layers.3.input_layernorm.weight', 'layers.3.mlp.down_proj.weight', 'layers.3.mlp.gate_proj.weight', 'layers.3.mlp.up_proj.weight', 'layers.3.post_attention_layernorm.weight', 'layers.3.self_attn.k_proj.weight', 'layers.3.self_attn.o_proj.weight', 'layers.3.self_attn.q_proj.weight', 'layers.3.self_attn.v_proj.weight', 'layers.4.input_layernorm.weight', 'layers.4.mlp.down_proj.weight', 'layers.4.mlp.gate_proj.weight', 'layers.4.mlp.up_proj.weight', 'layers.4.post_attention_layernorm.weight', 'layers.4.self_attn.k_proj.weight', 'layers.4.self_attn.o_proj.weight', 'layers.4.self_attn.q_proj.weight', 'layers.4.self_attn.v_proj.weight', 'layers.5.input_layernorm.weight', 'layers.5.mlp.down_proj.weight', 'layers.5.mlp.gate_proj.weight', 'layers.5.mlp.up_proj.weight', 'layers.5.post_attention_layernorm.weight', 'layers.5.self_attn.k_proj.weight', 'layers.5.self_attn.o_proj.weight', 'layers.5.self_attn.q_proj.weight', 'layers.5.self_attn.v_proj.weight', 'layers.6.input_layernorm.weight', 'layers.6.mlp.down_proj.weight', 'layers.6.mlp.gate_proj.weight', 'layers.6.mlp.up_proj.weight', 'layers.6.post_attention_layernorm.weight', 'layers.6.self_attn.k_proj.weight', 'layers.6.self_attn.o_proj.weight', 'layers.6.self_attn.q_proj.weight', 'layers.6.self_attn.v_proj.weight', 'layers.7.input_layernorm.weight', 'layers.7.mlp.down_proj.weight', 'layers.7.mlp.gate_proj.weight', 'layers.7.mlp.up_proj.weight', 'layers.7.post_attention_layernorm.weight', 'layers.7.self_attn.k_proj.weight', 'layers.7.self_attn.o_proj.weight', 'layers.7.self_attn.q_proj.weight', 'layers.7.self_attn.v_proj.weight', 'layers.8.input_layernorm.weight', 'layers.8.mlp.down_proj.weight', 'layers.8.mlp.gate_proj.weight', 'layers.8.mlp.up_proj.weight', 'layers.8.post_attention_layernorm.weight', 'layers.8.self_attn.k_proj.weight', 'layers.8.self_attn.o_proj.weight', 'layers.8.self_attn.q_proj.weight', 'layers.8.self_attn.v_proj.weight', 'layers.9.input_layernorm.weight', 'layers.9.mlp.down_proj.weight', 'layers.9.mlp.gate_proj.weight', 'layers.9.mlp.up_proj.weight', 'layers.9.post_attention_layernorm.weight', 'layers.9.self_attn.k_proj.weight', 'layers.9.self_attn.o_proj.weight', 'layers.9.self_attn.q_proj.weight', 'layers.9.self_attn.v_proj.weight', 'norm.weight', 'qa_outputs.bias', 'qa_outputs.weight']
You should probably TRAIN this model on a down-stream task to be able to use it for predictions and inference.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Levente\Desktop\minigpt\train.py", line 144, in <module>
    batch = data_collator.collate_batch(inputs)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Levente\Desktop\minigpt\train.py", line 61, in collate_batch
    "input_ids": torch.nn.utils.rnn.pad_sequence([i[0] for i in inputs], batch_first=True),
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Levente\Desktop\minigpt\.venv\Lib\site-packages\torch\nn\utils\rnn.py", line 399, in pad_sequence
    return torch._C._nn.pad_sequence(sequences, batch_first, padding_value)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
RuntimeError: The size of tensor a (349) must match the size of tensor b (327) at non-singleton dimension 1

What could be the solution to the problem to make the program run successfully? Unfortunately, time is pressing, and I'm quite puzzled.
Unfortunately, I've tried many things, but I've encountered various other problems. The data processing works fine, but the issue always arises when I pass it to the trainer. There was a problem with passing a list containing dictionaries, and another problem occurred with "Scalar tensor has no len()". What could be the solution? Could you help me fix the code?

Maybe first use print() (and print(type(...)), print(len(...)), etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called "print debugging" and it helps to see what code is really doing.

maybe you have to convert tensor to list which has len()

without example data we can't test it. And maybe all problem are wrong data.

https://huggingface.co/datasets/SzegedAI/MILQA/tree/main I use this data set, only I downloaded it, the train file and the test file as well.

add this to question - it will be move visible, and more people may see it, so more people may run code and help you.

Could someone please help me? I'm desperate, and I need to submit by May 18th."
